# Cannot find module './src/index.js'. Website works but why do I have to redploy to fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, webpack

Every time I make changes to my website, I fetch them from github.  I run webpack in the terminal, which appears to work.  Then I run my expressHost.js file to host my site.  When i access that site I get the error in the title.

To fix this i delete the folder, git clone, npm install, webpack, node expressHost.js  and it works like nothing was ever wrong.  any ideas?

Simular issues do not seem to be happening on my dev machine, only my VPS.

my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

my expressHost

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.listen(7070, () => {
    console.log('listening 7070...');
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

my public folder has index.html, bundle.js, and styles folder.  Everything was made using React and is hosted with nginx.  I am new to deployment, I have only launched one other site (which works, NG1)

this is the error i get when running webpack... this does not happen on the local machine.

```
Hash: d437a155a1da4cdfeeeb
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 77ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.51 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.
 @ multi main
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/259
https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/tutorials/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr

So I was having the error listed above but the page was still working on my local machine.  When I posted any changes I would get that error but it seemed to work,  When users viewed the machine they would get the error in the title.

to install babel loader correctly I have to change the webpack config to `module{ loaders {[ loader: 'babel-loader'`  this seemed to solve the issue of babel being moved into babel-core's folder

also (probably the real issue) npm needed to install, in terminal

```
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-1 -S
```

because the webpack config had  `module{ loaders {[ query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']`

the website appears to be fetching and compiling websites like normal.